# why is gzip better than compressed files in windows 2012

Tags: windows, gzip

I have a 4.7 Gb file that I wanted to store and move.  It is sitting on a Windows 2012 server.

When I used the advanced file option "compress to save disk space" the OS was able to reduce it to 3.013 GB, or about 64% of the original size.  This was good for while it was sitting on the server.

I had to move it, so I used my (90's era) favorite compression tool, gzip, and it was reduced to 2.294 Gb, or about 48.7% of the original size.

**Question**:
Why is "gzip" from the 90's able to make files whose footprint is 75% of what windows 2012 compression does?  Is this about "opening time"?  Is this a place where the open-source has a performance ability not present in a closed-source?  What gives?

Comment: This question can do without the not so subtle rant against closed-source software. Long story short: disk compression is optimized for access time and throughput, not compression ratio. Try searching. I'm also not entirely sure why this was posted on SO, as you're obviously not programming something yourself here.

Comment: Don't read things into it that are not there.  I know the folks in MS are bright and do things for a good reason.  I just want to know what the reason was.  It seems inconceivable that 20 year old software does something they didn't think of - so I want to know what they are thinking.

Comment: Or you don't post irrelevant details like "from the 90's" and "open-source versus closed-source" remarks? :) Anyway read [MSDN: File Compression and Decompression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219(v=vs.85).aspx) for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are doing different things.

NTFS compression has to support random access, including reading *and writing* data into the middle or beginning of a compressed file, which

a) may not be as compressible as the data which was there before (so all later data has to be moved)

b) will invalidate the dictionary used to compress the rest of the file (so it all needs to be rewritten)

Using GZIP would also mean that if you wished to read the last ten bytes of a file you would have to first decompress the whole thing, to get the compression dictionary into the correct state.

Therefore NTFS compresses the file in smallish blocks, and doesn't make use of similarities between widely separated parts of the file to increase compression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the internals but I would be willing to bet that both Windows and GZip are using the same Deflate compression algorithm. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE

Here is what I would imagine is accounting for the difference:

1. Deflate has a compression setting from 0-9 where 0 is no compression, 9 is best compression. All the values in-between have a trade off of speed vs compression. When windows is compressing your drive it is probably using a setting they have determined is a good trade off in terms of speed when you need to open your files.
2. I know you said you are operating on a single file, but often when people ask this question it is because GZip operates on a single file. This is why it is usually used in combination with Tar. Compressing a single file will always have an advantage over compressing multiple files individually (as .zip does).